# How to prevent IntelliJ from including 3rd-party JAR inside my JAR?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I prevent IntelliJ from including 3rd-party JARs inside my JAR ?

It's insanely annoying. Basically I want one of these:

- to produce jar with my code **only**. 3rd-party jar will be referenced in manifest.

OR

- to produce jar with extracted classes of 3rd-party libraries.

The only problem is that IntelliJ produces JAR with other jar files inside. They are useless because java doesn't see them anyway when I run my jar via `java -jar my.jar`. I have to manually delete them and repack JAR/ZIP file.

Dependencies are not marked as "Export" in Settings.

I think jars end up in my jar because I added "compile output" in layout of my artifact. But I'm not sure how I can make compile output without jars of dependencies.

I tried setting Scope of dependencies to "Provided". It didn't help. They still get copied to output.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is controlled by the following options when you create a jar artifact in IDEA:

[image: jar artifact]

[Refer to help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/create-jar-from-modules-dialog.html) for details.

Comment: It doesn't change the behavior. If I select first option it extracts dependencies to jar **and** copies dependent jars too. I'm using build 123.129.

Comment: Please share a sample project to reproduce.

Comment: Here is project files of the real project without sources: https://www.dropbox.com/s/erck35ejdruml5d/java_backfill.zip If it's not helpful I can create smaller on Monday. Thank you!! :)

Comment: The problem with your project is that `libs` folder is marked as **Sources**, therefore all the files from this folder are copied to output and are included to the artifacts. The solution is to remove this folder from sources or to adjust `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns` so that `.jar` files are not copied to output. By default library folders are never configured as **Sources**.

Comment: I thought about it too. I tried to mark it as Excluded but it didn't help. I'll try to create fresh sample project and let you know how it goes.

Comment: My god, those three buttons (Test, Source, Excluded) are **multiple selection!** I never noticed it. That helped. Thanks a lot!